# Selecting local minima and maxima from pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas

There is a [`scipy.signal.argrelextrema`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) function that works with `ndarray`, but when I try to use it on `pandas.Series`, it returns an error. What's the right way to use it with pandas?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
s = pd.Series(randn(10), range(10))
s
argrelextrema(s, np.greater)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-f3812e58bbe4> in <module>()
      4 s = pd.Series(randn(10), range(10))
      5 s
----> 6 argrelextrema(s, np.greater)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.pyc in argrelextrema(data, comparator, axis, order, mode)
    222     """
    223     results = _boolrelextrema(data, comparator,
--> 224                               axis, order, mode)
    225     return np.where(results)
    226 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.pyc in _boolrelextrema(data, comparator, axis, order, mode)
     60 
     61     results = np.ones(data.shape, dtype=bool)
---> 62     main = data.take(locs, axis=axis, mode=mode)
     63     for shift in xrange(1, order + 1):
     64         plus = data.take(locs + shift, axis=axis, mode=mode)

TypeError: take() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mode'
```

Comment: You may want to convert your data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array-include-index

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably want to use it like so,

```
argrelextrema(s.values, np.greater)
```

You are currently using the complete pandas Series while argrelextrema expects an nd array. s.values provides you with the nd.array

Answer (score 2):

Even though `s.values` still works fine (Pandas 0.25), the recommended way is now:

```
argrelextrema(s.to_numpy(), np.greater)
# equivalent to:
argrelextrema(s.to_numpy(copy=False), np.greater)
```

While there is also an `s.array` property, using it here will fail with: `TypeError: take() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`.

Note: `copy=False` means "don't force a copy", but it can still happen.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply
As your code showed up, your array which has been read by pandas should be turning to numpy array. So just try to change the data frame to numpy array by  `np.array`

```
g = np.array(s) # g is new variable notation
argrelextrema(g, np.greater)
```

or in a different shape

```
g = np.array(s) # g is new variable notation
argrelextrema(g, lambda a,b: (a>b) | (a<b))
```