# igraph Graph from numpy or pandas adjacency matrix

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, igraph

I have an adjacency matrix stored as a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
node_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,1,1],[4,0,2]],
    index=node_names, columns=node_names)
a_numpy = a.as_matrix()
```

I'd like to create an `igraph.Graph` from either the `pandas` or the `numpy` adjacency matrices. In an ideal world the nodes would be named as expected.

Is this possible? [The tutorial](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html) seems to be silent on the issue.

Comment: Strictly speaking, [adjacency matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) are boolean. What do the values in `a_numpy` actually mean? Are they connection weights?

Comment: @ali_m I meant them to mean edge weights.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In igraph you can use [`igraph.Graph.Adjacency`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Adjacency) to create a graph from an adjacency matrix without having to use `zip`. There are some things to be aware of when a weighted adjacency matrix is used and stored in a `np.array` or `pd.DataFrame`.

- `igraph.Graph.Adjacency` can't take an `np.array` as argument, but that is easily solved using [`tolist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).
- Integers in adjacency-matrix are interpreted as number of edges between nodes rather than weights, solved by using adjacency as boolean.

An example of how to do it:

```
import igraph
import pandas as pd

node_names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,1,1],[4,0,2]], index=node_names, columns=node_names)

# Get the values as np.array, it's more convenenient.
A = a.values

# Create graph, A.astype(bool).tolist() or (A / A).tolist() can also be used.
g = igraph.Graph.Adjacency((A > 0).tolist())

# Add edge weights and node labels.
g.es['weight'] = A[A.nonzero()]
g.vs['label'] = node_names  # or a.index/a.columns
```

You can reconstruct your adjacency dataframe using [`get_adjacency`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#get_adjacency) by:

```
df_from_g = pd.DataFrame(g.get_adjacency(attribute='weight').data,
                         columns=g.vs['label'], index=g.vs['label'])
(df_from_g == a).all().all()  # --> True
```

Comment: Perfect! +1 for the fact that `Adjacency` interprets numbers as a number of links, not the link weight.

Comment: How would you convert this graph to a directed version if the rows were the 'from' nodes and columns were the 'to' nodes.

Comment: `a.to_numpy()` [is preferred to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/6509615) `a.values`

Answer (score 14):

Strictly speaking, an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is boolean, with 1 indicating the presence of a connection and 0 indicating the absence. Since many of the values in your `a_numpy` matrix are > 1, I will assume that they correspond to edge weights in your graph.

```
import igraph

# get the row, col indices of the non-zero elements in your adjacency matrix
conn_indices = np.where(a_numpy)

# get the weights corresponding to these indices
weights = a_numpy[conn_indices]

# a sequence of (i, j) tuples, each corresponding to an edge from i -> j
edges = zip(*conn_indices)

# initialize the graph from the edge sequence
G = igraph.Graph(edges=edges, directed=True)

# assign node names and weights to be attributes of the vertices and edges
# respectively
G.vs['label'] = node_names
G.es['weight'] = weights

# I will also assign the weights to the 'width' attribute of the edges. this
# means that igraph.plot will set the line thicknesses according to the edge
# weights
G.es['width'] = weights

# plot the graph, just for fun
igraph.plot(G, layout="rt", labels=True, margin=80)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[This is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36625051) with [`igraph.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Weighted_Adjacency) as

```
g = igraph.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(a.to_numpy().tolist())
```

`pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix` [has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html),
so `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy` should be used instead.
Additionally the numpy.ndarray given by `a.to_numpy()` must be converted to a list with `tolist()` before being passed to `Weighted_Adjacency`.

The node names can be stored as another attribute with

```
g.vs['name'] = node_names
```