# How to iteratively create a vector with different name in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` `data.frame`

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'country':['C1','C1','C1','C1','C2','C2','C2','C2'],
                     'seg':    ['S1','S2','S1','S2','S1','S2','S1','S2'],
                     'agegroup':    ['1', '2', '2', '1','1', '2', '2', '1'],
                      'N' : [21,22,23,24,31,32,33,34]})
```

and a vector like

`vector = ['country', 'seg']`

what i want to do is to create two vectors with names `vector_country` and `vector_seg` which will contain the respective columns of the `temp`, in this case the columns `country` and `seg`

I have tried

```
for vec in vector:
    'vector_' + str(vec) = temp[[vec]]
```

So in the end I would like to end up with two vectors:

`vector_country`, which will contain the `temp.country` and

`vector_seg`, which will contain the `temp.seg`

Is it possible to do something like that in `python` ?

Comment: Is [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html) what you want? Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37043071/2454357)?

Comment: What's wrong with using ```vector_country=temp['country'].values; vector_seg=temp['seg'].values```?

Comment: @ThomasKühn neither. the problem is that i want to create two vectors with different names depending on the value of `vector`. I edited  my question. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: @TrigonaMinima because i want to do it in a standardized way for multiple columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try and dynamically name variables. This is bad practice, will make your code intractable.

A better alternative is to use dictionaries, as so:

```
v = {}

for vec in ['country', 'seg']:
    v[vec] = temp[vec].values
```

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go, but why would one want to switch from a DataFrame to storing arrays in a dict?

Comment: @ThomasKühn, if the dataframe is going to be discarded and you want to efficiently store the values for some later calculations. I don't know the complete workflow for quant's use case.