# Use previous data in rolling in Python

Tags: python, pandas, apply, rolling-computation

I would like to do the following in python

[image]

Basically I have a table as following with y = 0.5

```
A | B | Result from column A
---
1   2   0.5
---
2   4   0.5*(0.5+ 2)
---
3   5   ...
---
4   4   ...
---
```

So far I have a loop, which is not efficient, I would like a vectorised way of doing it :

```
X = np.zeros((len(df),))
for i, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    X[i] = y*(X[i - 1] +  row['A'])
```

Can you please help me on the above

Thank you

Comment: Post your code showing what you have done

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow!](https://stackoverflow.com) Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also like @SreeramTP said, you should share what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for your messages, Please find my code above, sorry for that. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure you can vectorized here because the Xn+1 depend on the Xn result.

Comment: Yeah, I need some kind of rolling apply, taking the previous result.

Comment: The for loop could be the better choice in this case due to result dependancy. Using  rolling imply knowing all data to which the function will be used on. that is not your case.

Comment: You cannot vectorize your iteration expression. But, since this is a numerical problem, I'd try running your loop using [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/). You need to [convert your `pandas` dataframe to a `numpy.ndarray`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array) though, because `numba` cannot work with dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you should use the Pandas rolling method joins with lambda expression, something similar to this:

```
X = [your_Pandas_Serie]
rolling_window = X.rolling([the_length_of_your_Serie])

rolling_window.apply(lambda x: [your_function])
```

Check out with simple rolling method like mean() to be familiar and get used of lambda expression before implementing your final solution.

I used the same kind of process in trading software.

Comment: Certainly must add condition for the first value.

Comment: But X are unknown here. You need to apply y and f with previous Xn to compute Xn+1. Can you do that with rolling function?