# convert Dataframe to 2d Array

Tags: python, dataframe, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have a data-frame of size (140000,22) dimensions.

i have to create 2d array of equal dimensions to pass it into convolution neural network .

Can you please guide how to transform on this dataframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 15):

**Edit:**
If by 'equal' dimensions you mean it should be a square array, this is not possible, since 140000*22 is not a square number. However, in general you don't need a square array to feed data into a CNN, but this of course depends on your specific CNN.

**Old answer:**
You just need to call `.values` on the DataFrame.

If for example your dataframe is called `df`, then you can pass `df.values` to your convolutional neural network.

Comment: Hi but the .values would give us a single array of whole dataframe right

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry I didn't see that you asked for equal dimensions. What dimensions do you want the array to have?

Comment: it should be 2D array of Equal dimensions so that i can fit it for a neural network

Comment: This is not the right answer at all : see the other comments

Answer (score 4):

Use `arr = df.to_numpy()`

See:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html

It will create a 2d array where each row is the inner array.

```
[[row1],
 [row2],
 [row3]...
 [row n]]
```

To turn it into a 2d array where each column is the inner array, use transpose:

`arr = np.transpose(arr)`

```
[[all_data_in_col_1],
 [all_data_in_col_2],...
 [all_data_in_col_n]]
```