# converting a dataframe in pandas to an array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert an excel sheet to a csv file, then converting that to a numpy array. However, when I use `Data = df.to_numpy()` it exports the first column as string variables, not float, while other values are perfectly converted. I don't know where the problems is coming from. Here is a sample of the output of Data[0]:

```
>>Data[0]
array(['0.01', 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0,
       0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0], dtype=object)
```

Here is the head of the data sheet in my excel sheet:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
filename = "C:/Users/IMET/Desktop/One/MCC-200.xlsx"
Col_Names=[
            "Size (um)-3 bar","Volume (%)-PreRC", 
            "Size (um)-0.5 bar","Volume (%)-PreRC",
            "Size (um)-3 bar","Volume (%)-457um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-0.5 bar","Volume (%)-457um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-3 bar","Volume (%)-610um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-0.5 bar","Volume (%)-610um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-3 bar","Volume (%)-813um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-0.5 bar","Volume (%)-813um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-3 bar","Volume (%)-991um-3500rpm",
            "Size (um)-0.5 bar","Volume (%)-991um-3500rpm"
           ]


df = pd.read_excel(filename,'PSDs').to_csv('MyCSV.csv',index=False)

df2 = pd.read_csv('MyCSV.csv',skiprows = 4)

df2.dropna(axis=1,inplace=True,how='all')
df2.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True,how='any')

df2.columns=Col_Names

Data = df2.to_numpy()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array/54508052#54508052

Comment: Also, we will need to see some of your data to understand the issue.

Comment: @coldspeed I added a snapshot of my excel file