# Pandas string series into several Boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I have a DF, with 2 columns, id and symptoms (int, string)
it looks like this:

```
id      symptoms
1       symptom1;symptom2 
2       symptom2;symptom3 
3       symptom1;symptom3;symptom4
```

I want it to change the columns to id, symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4,...
and the values in the new columns will be true/false depending on the original column.
so the first row will be: [id1, true, true, false, false,...]

I found this question which is close:
[Changing a string column into several boolean columns using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147641/changing-a-string-column-into-several-boolean-columns-using-pandas)

but in my case I might have several symptoms and I couldn't get it to work.

any advice on how to get to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `get_dummies`

```
out = df.join(df.pop('symptoms').str.get_dummies(';').astype(bool))
```