# Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making a  SVM Model to support my machine learning model." Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead". error keeps showing up after running my code. what should I do?

I've tried following it's instructions to change it to .values, however, compiler says that TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

here's the code:

```
d = pd.read_csv('voice.csv')
d.head()
sns.lmplot('IQR','meanfun', data=d, hue='label',
           palette='Set1', fit_reg=False, scatter_kws={'s': 1})
ERROR --> IQR_meanfun = d[['IQR','meanfun']].as_matrix()
type_label = np.where(d['Type']=='Male', 0, 1)
```

Comment: Use `DataFrame.to_numpy`

Comment: @DimaTisnek That has been suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55390914/4909087).

Comment: Nice, `* minds think alike!` @coldspeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; `as_matrix()` is a method, `values` is an attribute.

But both return a 2D array. `as_matrix()` is straight up deprecated, so using it is out of the question. That just leaves us with `values`, which is used like this:

```
IQR_meanfun = d[['IQR','meanfun']].values
```

(You probably called `.values()` which manifested as a `TypeError`.)

---

If you're running v0.24 or greater, `.values` is no longer the recommended method for extracting an array from a DataFrame. See [the docs](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#accessing-the-values-in-a-series-or-index), and [this answer which goes into this in gory detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array/54508052#54508052)

```
# Recommended method from v0.24 onwards,
# IQR_meanfun = d[['IQR','meanfun']].to_numpy(copy=True)
# Same as,
IQR_meanfun = d[['IQR','meanfun']].to_numpy()
```