# Pandas Dataframe groupby take lable included in numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to convert pandas dataframe to numpy array with the groupby lable with it.
In groupby I have to group by using regex so its important to take its lable with it.

My data is in the format:

```
start_date,is_member 

2014-04-15 00:01,1
2014-04-15 00:01,1
2014-04-15 01:01,1
2014-04-15 01:01,1
2014-04-15 02:02,1
2014-04-15 03:05,1
```

I have tried

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0)
df = df.groupby(df.start_date.str.extract("^(.*?)\:", expand=False))[['start_date']].count()[['start_date']]
print(df)
```

Output of Dataframe is

```
start_date               
2014-04-15 00           2
2014-04-15 01           2
2014-04-15 02           1
2014-04-15 03           1
```

I have tried it to convert into numpy array with

```
numpy_array = df.values
```

Output of numpy array is just the count value

```
[[2]
 [2]
 [1]
 [1]]
```

I want it with the startdate as a column.

```
[[2014-04-15 00 2]
 [2014-04-15 01 2]
 [2014-04-15 02 1]
 [2014-04-15 03 1]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
#simplify code 
df = df.groupby(df.start_date.str.extract("^(.*?)\:", expand=False))['start_date'].count()

numpy_array = df.rename_axis('index').reset_index().values
print (numpy_array)
[['2014-04-15 00' 2]
 ['2014-04-15 01' 2]
 ['2014-04-15 02' 1]
 ['2014-04-15 03' 1]]
```

Or [for pandas 0.24+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052) use:

```
numpy_array = df.rename_axis('index').reset_index().to_numpy()
```

Comment: When I am using .reset_index() it is giving error,  "cannot insert start_date, already exists". If you could help.