# How to remove the repeated row spaning two dataframe index in python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, repeat

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'location1': [1, 2,3,8,6], 'location2': 
[2,1,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

The dataframe `df` means there is a road between two locations. look like:

```
   location1    location2
0   1               2 
1   2               1
2   3               4 
3   8               6 
4   6               8
```

The first row means there is a road between `locationID1` and `locationID2`, however, the second row also encodes this information.  The forth and fifth rows also have repeated information.  I am trying the remove those repeated by keeping only one row. Any of row is okay.

For example, my expected output is

```
   location1    location2
0   1               2 
2   3               4 
4   6               8
```

Any efficient way to do that because I have a large dataframe with lots of repeated rows.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an efficient way to select multiple rows in a large pandas data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439420/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-select-multiple-rows-in-a-large-pandas-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want every other row in your dataframe. This should work.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'location1': [1, 2,3,8,6], 'location2': 
[2,1,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

   location1  location2
0          1          2
1          2          1
2          3          4
3          8          6
4          6          8

def Every_other_row(a):
    return a[::2]

Every_other_row(df)

   location1  location2
0          1          2
2          3          4
4          6          8
```