# Difference between to_numpy() vs .values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I saw it in the 0.24.2 pandas documentation [pandas.DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) that

```
Warning We recommend using DataFrame.to_numpy() instead.
```

Why is to_numpy() preferred over DataFrame.values? Can someone explain it in details?

I am asking this because I have probably written about hundreds of codes using DataFrame.values for converting a pandas DataFrame to numpy array thus far. If the underlying reason is serious, then I should probably go back to change everything with .values to to_numpy().

Comment: this might be worth a read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array/54508052#54508052

Comment: This  is a relatively new feature that appeared in version 24. I think it aims to give more flexibility in the way you extract the data to `numpy ndarray`, espescially in term of `dtype`. Therefore pandas recommend to use it instead of `.values`. But  I don't think you should worry, `.values` does not seem to be in deprecation so far!