# How to convert the list of Dataframes in this required shape of array?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes which looks like shown in image.

The list length is 200 where it has 200 dataframes, each dataframe has length of 205 and has 6 columns.

I want to bring this list in the array of shape (200,205,6)

I tried it doing follwing method but I keep getting the error given below.

np.array(samples).reshape(200,205,6)

For this code I am getting an error:

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 205 to array axis with dimension 1

I also removed 5 columns and kept only one column in all datarames but yet  am getting same error.

Is there any way to bring it in the required shape..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLVvb.png)

Comment: still not very clear what you want to do - do you want to take all the values in the dataframes and create a nested array from the dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because numpy doesn't know how to convert a pandas dataframe into an np.array, but you can solve this pretty quickly:

`np.array([df.values for for df in list_of_dataframes])`

I tried it with this sample data:

```
data = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((205,6))) for i in range(200)]

np.array([df.values for df in data]).shape
```

(200, 205, 6)

PS: Possibly a duplicate of:
[Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)