# Effective way to get array from pandas dataframe text column

Tags: python, pandas

Can I do the following conversion to an array, using constructs like `df.col.apply(lambda x ...` , without using 'traditional' for-loops (one iterating over the columns and another iterating over words within each column's string value)?

All my attempts gave error messages like `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Example:

```py
d = {'foo' : [1,2,3], 'bar': [-2,-2,-3]}
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['foo mur bar','foo','mur mur']}, index=[1,2,3])
```

Expected output is:

```
np.array([
    [[1,2,3],[-2,-2,-3]],
    [[1,2,3]],
    [[]]
])
```

Comment: Yes. There are 385 existing results for [*\[python\] create word vector*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+create+word-vector), please search through them. This is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
a = df['col'].str.split().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).map(d)).values
a = np.array([pd.Series(i).dropna().values for i in a])
print(a)
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 2, 3], [-2, -2, -3]], dtype=object)
 array([[1, 2, 3]], dtype=object) array([], dtype=object)]
```

Comment: thank you. I could do it by ```np.array(df1.col.apply(lambda x: np.array([d[item] for item in x.split(' ') if d.get(item, 0) != 0])))``` but you way more quickly imho.