# How to get the each rows in a pandas to a np arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Assume this is my dataframe looks like

```
DF:
    A  B  C
    1  10 10
    2  5  5
    3  12 12
    4   6 7   
    5  21 22
```

Actually i need the help of how can i get each rows as np arrays.
In each iteration with iterrows() or itertuples():
like

```
[1,10,10]
[2,5,5]
etc...
```

I see the thread which all convert to np arrays from the dataframe only.
So kindly suggest me how can we achieve this.

Comment: do `df.vallues`

Comment: With `df.values`?

Comment: With [`df.to_numpy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/4909087).

Comment: Df.values will convert total df to np arrays right? With my understanding ? Sorry

Comment: `a, b, c, d, e = df.to_numpy()` will unpack each row into separate variables, not that that makes much sense.

Comment: I need to iterate each rows and convert that row only to the np arrays

Comment: No, you don't need to iterate over each row. This sounds like an XY problem. It'd be great if you could explain the problem you're trying to solve instead of asking how to do something you _think_ is the solution to that problem.

Comment: @cs95 actually I cannot say it will contain 5 rows only it may contain 100 rows also

Comment: @cs95 yeah sorry about that! I'm trying that I need to read the csv and I have around 205 columns and numerous rows in that! So I need to write values of the rows to the text file using np.savetxt method with formatting in the append mode and I need to append all the values from rows to the text file one by one.so that I need np arrays which contains all the values in each rows.

Comment: Please edit your question with this information, I'll be happy to reopen so others can answer.