# Python DataFrame count how many different elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to count how many different elements are in my DataFrame (df).

My df has the day of the month (as a number: 1,2,3 ... 31) in which a certain variable was measured. There are 3 columns that describe the number of the day. There are multiple measurements in one day so my columns have repeated values. I need to know how many days in a month was that variable measured ignoring how many times a day was that measurement done. So I was thinking that counting the days ignoring repeated values.

As an example the data of my df would look like this:

```
col1 col2 col3   
 2    2   2
 2    2   3
 3    3   3
 3    4   8
```

I need an output that tells me that in that DataFrame the numbers are 2, 3, 4 and 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide labels for your data sample?

Comment: i named the columns with a generic name. is that ok?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataset as well as the expected results.  Thanks.

Comment: well I cant work out how you get 6 measurements and 3 measurements

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({"col1": [2,2,3,3], "col2": [2,2,3,4], "col3": [2,3,3,8]})

df.stack().unique()
```

Outputs:

```py
[2 3 4 8]
```

Comment: Do you know how this compares performance-wise to `pd.unique(df.to_numpy().flatten())` ?

Comment: Less operations- for starters. It's purely ```pandas``` solution (even though it returns ```numpy```), instead of jumping between ```pandas```, ```numpy```, and again ```pandas```.

Comment: I'm running some benchmarks, and so far `df.stack().unique()` actually appears to be a bit slower. WIP

Comment: As far as I can tell `pd.unique(df.to_numpy().flatten())` is actually consistently faster than `df.stack().unique()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) into your dataframe, like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2,2,3], 'b':[2,2,3], 'c':[2,2,3]})

   a  b  c
0  2  2  2
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3

df = df.drop_duplicates()
print(df['a'].count())
out: 2
```

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `df.count()`, since we want the total number of unique values across the entire DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use numpy to get the unique values in the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [2, 2, 3, 3], 'Y' : [2,2,3,4], 'Z' : [2,3,3,8]})

df_unique = np.unique(np.array(df))

print(df_unique) 
#Output [2 3 4 8]
#for the count of days:
print(len(df_unique))
#Output 4
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Assuming this is your initial df:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     2     2     2
1     2     2     2
2     3     3     3
```

Then:

```
count_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df.columns:
    df2 = df[i].value_counts()
    count_df = pd.concat([count_df, df2], axis=1)

final_df = count_df.sum(axis=1)
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data=final_df, columns=['Occurrences'])
print(final_df)

   Occurrences
2            6
3            3
```

Comment: Edit: Converted series to df to make it look tidier

Comment: As your question has changed, this answer no longer applies.

Comment: Repeatedly concatenating like that can destroy performance, it's probably best to add all the parts to a temporary data structure and concat once. Although the ideal would be to avoid explicitly looping entirely, it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Even when his question was changed after my answer, I tested 3 different approaches and this was the fastest. I tested with a 10,000,000 x 3 dataframe and got a faster time with this method than using stack() or to_numpy.flatten() and counting occurrences. I disagree with your downvote here

Comment: That’s certainly unexpected, I’ll take a look at the performance in a bit.

Comment: Please, share results. It took 0.8 seconds to run the above code whereas it took 1.6ish seconds to run the other two alternatives.

Comment: Did you make any tweaks to the various solutions in order to benchmark them? Yours returns both the unique values and their frequency, not just the total number of unique values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209179/discussion-between-teoeme139-and-amc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html#pandas-unique) like so:

```py
pd.unique(df.to_numpy().flatten())
```

I have done some basic benchmarking, this method appears to be the fastest.

Comment: adding the benchmarking to the post would be useful

Comment: @baxx Yes, I intend on doing so tomorrow!

Comment: I'd be interested on the use of `to_numpy()` over `values` here as well, perhaps it's just whatever was first to mind. I couldn't think of a reason for one over the other though (perhaps that will be clear with the benchmarks?)

Comment: @baxx It isn’t for performance reasons, although I am now curious to know if there is one, you can find a good explanation of `.values` and `.to_numpy()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/11301900).

Comment: ah, I hadn't seen that information, thanks for the link. I'll stop using values, and think that's good reason to use `to_numpy` instead.

Comment: @baxx Until I do manage to write a proper answer, you can find some of my benchmarks posted [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209179/discussion-between-teoeme139-and-amc).