# Find mapping of changes of pandas methods from one version to another

Tags: python, pandas, methods

Newbie Q here, but is there a mapping for changes/replacements of methods from one version of pandas to another?

Example: am working with pandas 1.0.3 in a local Jupyter notebook created from an online course Jupyter notebook from 2 or more years ago. Getting a `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'as_matrix'` attribute error, so I believe the `.as_matrix()` method is from pandas 0.2X. I'd like to be able to find a page that shows which methods are changed or deprecated from one version of pandas to another.

Comment: Usually the documentation page has information on the functions that have been depreciate, they link to the new function page which you should use in the latest version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Comment: techytushar: thanks, I suppose that is as close to a mapping as may be found? Alexandre B. : doesn't answer my specific Q, but it is useful in its own right; thanks.