# How to store a dataframe's values in a single list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe called table and want to store all its cell values in a single list:

```
table = pd.DataFrame({'col-1':[2,7,13,16,23,26,27,29], 'col-2':[541,3,0,15,329,525,6,28], 'col-3':[0,571,0,9,9,0,62,0]}, index=['row-1','row-2','row-3','row-4','row-5','row-6','row-7','row-8'])
```

The final output should be like this:

```
my_list = [2,7,13,16,23,26,27,29,541,3,0,15,329,525,6,28,0,571,0,9,9,0,62,0]
```

Will appreciate it if you can teach me the most efficient way to undertake this task. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
my_list = table.melt()['value'].tolist()
print(my_list)
```

Alternatively, you could also try  variations of @DavidK's Answer with [`to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy), which is [recommended](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) by pandas and also discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array):

```
my_list = df.T.to_numpy().ravel().tolist()
print(my_list)
```

```
my_list = df.T.to_numpy().reshape(-1).tolist()
print(my_list)
```

**Output in either case**:

```
[2, 7, 13, 16, 23, 26, 27, 29, 541, 3, 0, 15, 329, 525, 6, 28, 0, 571, 0, 9, 9, 0, 62, 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

For better perfomance is used `numpy` method [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with transposed data:

```
import numpy as np

L = np.ravel(table.T).tolist()
```

Idea with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) is also possible, but if huge df performance should be worse:

```
L = table.unstack().tolist()
```

---

```
print (L)
[2, 7, 13, 16, 23, 26, 27, 29, 541, 3, 0, 15, 329, 525, 6, 28, 0, 571, 0, 9, 9, 0, 62, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael for your great solution. It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could use :

```
my_list = table.T.values.flatten().tolist()
```

*tanspose **.T*** is used to get the same order as your example

Comment: Thanks David for sharing this method with me. The issue is now fixed.