# Getting error: KeyError: 'Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings.' when trying to do pandas Smote algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, smote

My data is slightly unbalanced, so I am trying to do a SMOTE algorithm before doing the logistic regression model. When I do, I get the error: KeyError: 'Only the Series name can be used for the key in Series dtype mappings.' Could someone help me figure out why?
Here is the code:

```
X = dummies.loc[:, dummies.columns != 'Count']
y = dummies.loc[:, dummies.columns == 'Count']
#from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
os = SMOTE(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
columns = X_train.columns
os_data_X,os_data_y=os.fit_sample(X_train, y_train) # here is where it errors
os_data_X = pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_X,columns=columns )
os_data_y= pd.DataFrame(data=os_data_y,columns=['Count'])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `os_data_y= pd.DataFrame({Count':os_data_y})`

Comment: @QuangHoang thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it did not fix my error, since the error was on the fit_sample() line.

Comment: Try `y = dummies.loc[:, 'Count']`

Comment: @QuangHoang Unfortunately same error still

Answer (score 18):

I just encountered this problem myself. As it turned out, I had a duplicate column in my dataset. Perhaps double check that this is not the case for your dataset.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked if I do and there is not a duplicate column

Comment: it was also my case... Double check for duplications of the column names.

Comment: Same problem and your solution fixed it! Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error is mainly due to the fact that you have duplicate columns in your data. To check for duplicate columns, use:

```
df.head()
```

or `df.columns`

To fix, drop columns using:

```
df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

to drop the duplicated column(s).

Answer (score 1):

I actually just fixed this problem! I made them matrices: os_data_X,os_data_y=os.fit_sample(X_train.as_matrix(), y_train.as_matrix())

Comment: as_matrix is deprecated for more recent versions of pandas. This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array recommends to_numpy or values.

Answer (score 1):

100% correct solution.

Try to convert your X features into an array first and then feed to SMOTE:

sm = SMOTE()

X=np.array(X)

X, y = sm.fit_sample(X, y.ravel())