# How to get real and imaginary parts of a column in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

I have a dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cmplxnumbers':[1+1j,2-2j,3*(1+1j)]})
```

I need to get the imaginary parts of the numbers in the column.

I do it by:

```
df.cmplxnumbers.apply(lambda number: number.imag)
```

I get as a result:

```
0    1.0
1   -2.0
2    3.0
Name: cmplxnumbers, dtype: float64
```

Which is as expected.

Is there any quicker, more straightforward method, perhaps not involving the `lambda` function?

Comment: Do you have some speed problem to report?  This is pretty straightforward, as solutions go.  You need to apply the `.imag` qualifier (essentially a `get` function call) to each element of the column.  The `lambda` constructor is applied only once; the resulting function lives until the entire column is handled.

Comment: I don't have a speed problem in particular, I didn't find a better answer to the question than the one I presented, and it seemed odd that there isn't an easier way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pandas DataFrame/Series builds on top of numpy array, so they can be passed to most numpy functions.

In this case, you can try the following, which should be faster than the non-vectorized `.apply`:

```
df['imag'] = np.imag(df.cmplxnumbers)
df['real'] = np.real(df.cmplxnumbers)
```

Output:

```
         cmplxnumbers  imag  real
0  1.000000+1.000000j   1.0   1.0
1  2.000000-2.000000j  -2.0   2.0
2  3.000000+3.000000j   3.0   3.0
```

Or you can do `agg`:

```
df[['real','imag']] = df.cmplxnumbers.agg([np.real, np.imag])
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me using pandas v1.4.1: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cmplxnumbers'

Comment: @nicrie 'cmplxnumbers' here is the column name, you can replace `df.cmplxnumbers` with the actual column in your data, e.g. `df['col1']`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.to_numpy()` method of a Pandas object to get a NumPy array, which then has the `real` and `imag` fields. In summary:

```py
real_part = pd_obj.to_numpy().real
imag_part = pd_obj.to_numpy().imag
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/3372061) a discussion about `.values` vs `.array` vs `.to_numpy()`.

Comment: Nice. [The docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) say "We recommend using Series.array or Series.to_numpy(), depending on whether you need a reference to the underlying data or a NumPy array", so I think `to_numpy()` is probably better.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer. Also, note that a `DataFrame` doesn't have an `.array` field.