# finding duplicates and adding ID as attribute pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I'm working in geopandas with a large number (around 4.5 million) objects, where each has a unique ID number ('PARCEL_SPI') and also another code ('PC_PLANNO').

What I would like to do is write some code that, for each object, finds all other objects with the same PLANNO and adds their ID number as a list in a new attribute, say 'Same_code' for the object. The df is called spine_copy.

Here's a quick sample of what I have:

| PARCEL_SPI | PC_PLANNO |
| --- | --- |
| 23908 | LP12345 |
| 90435 | LP12345 |
| 329048 | LP90803 |
| 6409 | LP2399 |
| 34534 | LP90803 |
| 092824 | LP12345 |

and what I want out:

| PARCEL_SPI | PC_PLANNO | Same_code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23908 | LP12345 | [90435, 092824] |
| 90435 | LP12345 | [23908,092824] |
| 329048 | LP90803 | 34534 |
| 6409 | LP2399 | None |
| 34534 | LP90803 | 329048 |
| 092824 | LP12345 | [23908, 90435] |

I'm not too sure how to do this, but here's my attempt using groupby:

```
spine_copy.groupby('PC_PLANNO')['PARCEL_SPI'].apply(list)
```

However, this doesn't add the list as a new attribute for each object, and I'm unsure how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected ouput?

Comment: good point, added!

Comment: What is ouput if added new row `1111  LP12345` ?

Comment: Unfortunately needs to be a new attribute - the output for this project is basically a large database with attributes for each object

Comment: So how is changed expected ouput? Can you add to question?

Comment: How you've done it in your answer below is perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here converting to list is not necessary - filter duplciated rows by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and for it use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with invert mask passed to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = spine_copy['PC_PLANNO'].duplicated(keep=False)
s = spine_copy.groupby('PC_PLANNO')['PARCEL_SPI'].transform(lambda x: x.to_numpy()[::-1])
spine_copy['Same_code'] = np.where(m, s, None)
print (spine_copy)
   PARCEL_SPI PC_PLANNO Same_code
0       23908   LP12345     90435
1       90435   LP12345     23908
2      329048   LP90803     34534
3        6409    LP2399      None
4       34534   LP90803    329048
```

EDIT: with new data:

```
m = spine_copy['PC_PLANNO'].duplicated(keep=False)

new = spine_copy.groupby('PC_PLANNO')['PARCEL_SPI'].apply(list).rename('Same_code')
vals = spine_copy.join(new, on='PC_PLANNO')[['PARCEL_SPI','Same_code']]
s = [[z for z in y if z != x] for x, y in vals.to_numpy()]

spine_copy['Same_code'] = np.where(m, s, None)
print (spine_copy)
   PARCEL_SPI PC_PLANNO       Same_code
0       23908   LP12345  [90435, 92824]
1       90435   LP12345  [23908, 92824]
2      329048   LP90803         [34534]
3        6409    LP2399            None
4       34534   LP90803        [329048]
5       92824   LP12345  [23908, 90435]
```

Comment: Seen you prefer to use `.to_numpy()`  instead of `.values`.   Any reason for that ?  Just curious.

Comment: @SeaBean - sure, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/2901002)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the reason.   Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Thank you @jezrael! Just curious - will this also work if there are multiple with the same code? In some instances there are several dozen

Comment: @lev72748 - Not sure if understand, my code only invert order.

Comment: @jezrael I mean, in the actual data there will be many objects that have the same PC_PLANNO, so some objects will need to have multiple PARCEL_SPIs appearing in the Same_code column

Comment: @lev72748 - Without sample data + expected ouput I have no idea what you think. Unfortuantely.

Comment: @jezrael I've edited the question to show what I mean: consider the PC_PLANNO LP12345 - since there are 3 objects with the same value, there would be 2 entries appearing in the Same_code column (I've shown this as a list in the desired output)

Comment: @lev72748 - Give me some time for nswer with nw data

Comment: @lev72748 - added new solution to answer.

Comment: @jezrael thanks so much, great solution!

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try:

```
other = df.groupby('PC_PLANNO')['PARCEL_SPI'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
df = df.merge(other.rename(columns={'PARCEL_SPI':'Same_code'}), how='left', on=['PC_PLANNO'])
df['Same_code'] = df[['PARCEL_SPI', 'Same_code']].apply(lambda x: list(set(x['Same_code']) - set([x['PARCEL_SPI']])), axis=1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   PARCEL_SPI PC_PLANNO Same_code
0       23908   LP12345   [90435]
1       90435   LP12345   [23908]
2      329048   LP90803   [34534]
3        6409    LP2399        []
4       34534   LP90803  [329048]
```