# Why is np.shape not showing all dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas column storing a np array in each row. The df looks like this:

```
0    [38, 324, -21]
1    [41, 325, -19]
2    [41, 325, -19]
3    [42, 326, -20]
4    [42, 326, -19]
```

I want to convert this column into a np array so I can use it as training data for a model. I convert it to one np array with this:

```
arr = df.c.values
```

Now, I would except the shape of this array to be `(5,3)`. However, when I run:

```
arr.shape
```

I get this:

```
(5,)
```

Further, if I run:

```
arr[0].shape
```

I get `(3,)`.

Why don't I just get shape `(5,3)` when I run `arr.shape`?

Comment: `arr = np.array(df.c.to_list())`.

Comment: It is object dtype., 5 separate arrays, not one 2d one.  That's how they are stored in the frame.

Comment: Since there's no guarantee all elements in the column have the same length, `.values` will not return a 2D array for you. However you can manually construct an array like @QuangHoang commented.

Comment: @QuangHoang Ahh, you are right. Forget `df.c.values` is already a numpy array.

Comment: Maybe `df[['c']].values`

Comment: I think this question is actually answered, and is about [how to convert a pandas table to a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Comment: I think that the thing with OP here is that each row of colum `"c"` is a numpy array. So `df.c.values` nor df.c.to_numpy()` wont give the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at what df.c.values actually is by seeing what the output is:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c'] = [np.random.randint(0, 10, 3) for i in range(5)]
```

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    c
0   [-80, 4, -84]
1   [88, 32, 85]
2   [-11, 71, 37]
3   [-78, 93, 50]
4   [30, 29, 28]
```

```
In[3]: df.c.values
Out[3]: 
array([array([-80,   4, -84]), array([88, 32, 85]),
       array([-11,  71,  37]), array([-78,  93,  50]),
       array([30, 29, 28])], dtype=object)
```

So `df.c.values` is an 1 dimensional array containing 5 individual arrays (hence `df.c.values.shape == (5,)`), **and not** a 2d array.

To get a nd array you need to combine/stack them into *one* nd array. A straightforward way is to `np.vstack()` them:

```
arr = np.vstack(df.c.values)
arr.shape == (5,3)
```