# What is the difference between `pandas.Series.ravel()`, `pandas.Series.to_numpy()`, `pandas.Series.values` and `pandas.Series.array`?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Basically the title sums it up. I have created a dummy `pandas.Series` object and looked up all these properties and methods. Documentation states that all of them except maybe `pandas.array` return `numpy.ndarray` objects. What is the difference then and when should I use one method or attribute or another? I've read that for example there is some difference between `numpy.flatten()` and `numpy.ravel()`, the former returns new array and the latter returns the view. It is the same with `pandas`?

```py
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(10))
s.ravel()  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
s.to_numpy()  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
s.values  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
s.array  # <PandasArray>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all of these return a view:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(range(10))
rav = s.ravel()  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
to_num = s.to_numpy()  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
values = s.values  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
array = s.array  # <PandasArray>

rav[0] = 1
print('ravel', s[0])

to_num[0] = 2
print('to_numpy', s[0])

values[0] = 3
print('values', s[0])

array[0] = 4
print('array', s[0])
```

```
ravel 1
to_numpy 2
values 3
array 4
```

However, `to_numpy()` has the `copy` parameter (default `False`), with which you can return a full copy of the underlying array:

```
to_num_copy = s.to_numpy(copy=True)  # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

to_num_copy[0] = 5
print('to_numpy with copy', s[0])
```

```
to_numpy with copy 4
```

Finally, `to_numpy()` may sometimes also return a copy when the `dtype` of the column is not homogeneous and/or not a `numpy dtype`. Instead, `.array` should be used if we want to strictly avoid a copy.

Note that `.values` is considered old an instead `.array` or `to_numpy()` should be used. More info [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54508052/2246849).