# Convert a dataframe to an array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like the following.

| i | j | element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 0 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 9 |

How can I convert it to the 3*3 array below?

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas dataframe to NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the dataframe is called `df`, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as follows, with `.to_numpy()` (recommended) or `.values` as follows

```
array = df.pivot(index='i', columns='j', values='element').to_numpy()

# or

array = df.pivot(index='i', columns='j', values='element').values

[Out]:

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you transform your dataframe into three lists where the first is containing "i" values, the second - j and the third is data, you can create NumPy array "manually":

```
i, j, v = zip(*[x for x in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)])
arr = np.zeros(df.shape)
arr[i, j] = v
```