# How to calculate the expectation value for a given probability distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am writing a  program to determine the expectation value, expectation of the X^2 and E(X - X_avg)^2.  I have written a program like so:

```
# program : expectation value
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import chi2_contingency

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Step 1: read csv
probabilityCSV       = open('probability.csv')
df      = pd.read_csv(probabilityCSV) 
logging.debug(df['X'])
logging.debug(df['P'])
logging.debug(type(df['X']))
logging.debug(type(df['P']))

# Step 2: convert dataframe to ndarry
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array
X = df['X'].to_numpy()
p = df['P'].to_numpy()
logging.debug(f'X={X}')
logging.debug(f'p={p}')

# Step 3: calculate E(X)
# https://www.statology.org/expected-value-in-python/
def expected_value(values, weights):
    return np.sum((np.dot(values,weights))) / np.sum(weights)

logging.debug('Step 3: calculate E(X)')
expectation = expected_value(X,p)
logging.debug(f'E(X)={expectation}')


# Step 4: calculate E(X^2)
logging.debug('Step 4: calculate E(X^2)')
# add normalize='index'
contingency_pct = pd.crosstab(df['Observed'],df['Expected'],normalize='index')
logging.debug(f'contingency_pct:{contingency_pct}')


# Step 5: calculate E(X - X_avg)^2
logging.debug('Step 5: calculate E(X - X_avg)^2')
```

The dataset that I am using is:

```
X,P
8,1/8
12,1/6
16,3/8
20,1/4
24,1/12
```

Expected:

E(X) = 16
E(X^2) = 276
E(X- X_avg)^2 =20

Actual:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/evangertis/development/PythonAutomation/Statistics/expectation.py", line 35, in <module>
    expectation = expected_value(X,p)
  File "/Users/evangertis/development/PythonAutomation/Statistics/expectation.py", line 32, in expected_value
    return np.sum((np.dot(values,weights))) / np.sum(weights)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in sum
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2259, in sum
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 86, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the step 1, so I took the liberty of rewriting it:

```
# Step 1.1: read csv in the right way
probabilityCSV = open('probability.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(probabilityCSV)
df["P"] = df.P.str.split("/", expand=True)[0].astype(int) / df.P.str.split("/", expand=True)[1].astype(int)
```

`df`:

```
    X   P
0   8   0.125000
1   12  0.166667
2   16  0.375000
3   20  0.250000
4   24  0.083333
```

The second step is right:

```
# Step 2: convert dataframe to ndarry
X = df['X'].to_numpy()
p = df['P'].to_numpy()
```

`X, p`:

```
(array([ 8, 12, 16, 20, 24]),
 array([0.125     , 0.16666667, 0.375     , 0.25      , 0.08333333]))
```

After this you correctly defined the function:

```
def expected_value(values, weights):
    return np.sum((np.dot(values,weights))) / np.sum(weights)
```

You can use this function to compute `E(X)`, `E(X^2)` and `E(X - X_avg)^2`. In particular:

```
expected_value(X,p)
# returns E(X) = 16.0

expected_value(X**2, p)
# returns E(X^2) = 276.0

expected_value((X-X.mean())**2, p)
# returns E(X - X_avg)^2 = 20.0
```

The error has occurred because your `df["P"]` column is a string column.

Comment: What is the meaning of this line: df["P"] = df.P.str.split("/", expand=True)[0].astype(int) / df.P.str.split("/", expand=True)[1].astype(int) ? Specifically, the "/".

Comment: since `df["P"]` is a string type containing fractions like `"N/D"`, this line works in this way: splits the strings at the `"/"` and converts both first elements (the numerators N) and second elements (denominators D) in numeric type; then compute the values of the fractions and overwrite the `df["P"]` with these values.