# Converting numpy string array to float: Bizarre?

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion

So, this *should* be a really straightforward thing but for whatever reason, nothing I'm doing to convert an array of strings to an array of floats is working.

I have a two column array, like so:

```
Name    Value
Bob     4.56
Sam     5.22
Amy     1.22
```

I try this:

```
for row in myarray[1:,]:
     row[1]=float(row[1])
```

And this:

```
for row in myarray[1:,]:
    row[1]=row[1].astype(1)
```

And this:

```
myarray[1:,1] = map(float, myarray[1:,1])
```

And they all seem to do something, but when I double check:

```
type(myarray[9,1])
```

I get

```
<type> 'numpy.string_'>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949427/how-to-change-the-dtype-of-a-numpy-recarray

Comment: Aside: if you're working with mixed-type data, it might be worth your time to look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).  It already incorporates a lot of the tools you'd otherwise need to reimplement in order to get pure `numpy` to do the sort of ops people usually perform on names-and-numbers datasets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Numpy arrays must have one `dtype` unless it is structured.  Since you have some strings in the array, they must all be strings.

If you wish to have a complex `dtype`, you may do so:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([('Bob','4.56'), ('Sam','5.22'),('Amy', '1.22')], dtype = [('name','S3'),('val',float)])
```

Note that `a` is now a [1d structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), where each element is a tuple of type `dtype`.

You can access the values using their field name:

```
In [21]: a = np.array([('Bob','4.56'), ('Sam','5.22'),('Amy', '1.22')],
    ...:         dtype = [('name','S3'),('val',float)])

In [22]: a
Out[22]: 
array([('Bob', 4.56), ('Sam', 5.22), ('Amy', 1.22)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S3'), ('val', '<f8')])

In [23]: a['val']
Out[23]: array([ 4.56,  5.22,  1.22])

In [24]: a['name']
Out[24]: 
array(['Bob', 'Sam', 'Amy'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of the objects in a numpy array is determined at the initialsation of that array. If you want to change that later, you must cast the array, not the objects within that array.

```
myNewArray = myArray.asType(float)
```

Note: Upcasting is possible, for downcasting you need the astype method.
For further information see:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.astype.html

Comment: But the array has strings like `'Bob'` which cannot be converted into a float, so it will give `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bob'`