# Python: Create structured numpy structured array from two columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

How do you create a structured array from two columns in a DataFrame?
I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[10,20]], columns=['a','b'])
df

    a   b
0   1   2
1   10  20

x = np.array([([val for val in list(df['a'])],
               [val for val in list(df['b'])])])
```

But this gives me this:

```
array([[[ 1, 10],
        [ 2, 20]]])
```

But I wanted this:

```
[(1,2),(10,20)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because a package that I am using only takes input as a structured array. 
Why is this important?

Comment: Because there might be no need to create a list of tuple at all or it's also useful in terms of the way of creating that list of tuple.

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple of methods. You may experience a loss in performance and functionality relative to regular NumPy arrays.

#### record array

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) with `index=False`. Technically, this is a [record array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html), but for many purposes this will be sufficient.

```
res1 = df.to_records(index=False)

print(res1)

rec.array([(1, 2), (10, 20)], 
          dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8')])
```

#### structured array

Manually, you can construct a structured array via conversion to `tuple` by row, then specifying a list of tuples for the `dtype` parameter.

```
s = df.dtypes
res2 = np.array([tuple(x) for x in df.values], dtype=list(zip(s.index, s)))

print(res2)

array([(1, 2), (10, 20)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8')])
```

**What's the difference?**

Very little. `recarray` is a subclass of `ndarray`, the regular NumPy array type. On the other hand, the structured array in the second example is of type `ndarray`.

```
type(res1)                    # numpy.recarray
isinstance(res1, np.ndarray)  # True
type(res2)                    # numpy.ndarray
```

The main difference is record arrays facilitate attribute lookup, while structured arrays will yield `AttributeError`:

```
print(res1.a)
array([ 1, 10], dtype=int64)

print(res2.a)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Related: [NumPy “record array” or “structured array” or “recarray”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935940/9209546)

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension for convert nested `list`s to `tuple`s:

```
print ([tuple(x) for x in df.values.tolist()])
[(1, 2), (10, 20)]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.values.tolist())
[[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

EDIT: You can convert by [`to_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) and then to `np.asarray`, check [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16561#issuecomment-305341693):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[True, 1,2],[False, 10,20]], columns=['a','b','c'])
print (df)
       a   b   c
0   True   1   2
1  False  10  20

print (np.asarray(df.to_records(index=False)))
[( True,  1,  2) (False, 10, 20)]
```

Comment: Neither are numpy structured arrays. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @KimO - Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html
The result should be: array([(x,y), (x2,y2)]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
list(df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1))
```

or

```
df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x), axis=1).values
```

Comment: This is not a numpy structured array.. is that possible?

Comment: edited it, is the second version what you are looking for?

Comment: YES! 
Is there are way to control the types of the fields? For example, if the dataFrame has two columns and I want the first to turn into a "binary class event indicator"? As explained here: https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sksurv.ensemble.GradientBoostingSurvivalAnalysis.html#sksurv.ensemble.GradientBoostingSurvivalAnalysis.fit Search for "structured array" .. So "bool" type

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't use `object` dtype for integers, even with structured arrays.