# setting type of numpy structure array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy structured array where I need to control the data types of the individual elements.

This is my example:

```
y = array([(True, 144.0), 
           (True, 86.0), 
           (True, 448.0), 
           (True, 76.0), 
           (True, 511.0)], dtype=object)
```

If I do:

```
print(y.dtype.fields)
```

I get back:

```
None
```

However, what I wanted was "bool" and "float". 
If I access the individual elements, such as `y[0][0]` and `y[0][1]` I surely see that they are indeed bool and float.
I am super confused with this. Any ideas?

I need this because I use the packge "sciki-survival gradient boosting":https://scikit-survival.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/sksurv.ensemble.GradientBoostingSurvivalAnalysis.html#sksurv.ensemble.GradientBoostingSurvivalAnalysis.fit 
Where the input needs to be a structured array of type "bool" and "float".

Comment: what does `y.dtype` give you?

Comment: It gives `dtype('O')`, ie `np.object_`. This isn't a structured array

Comment: @Eric How do do I build a structured array then with the same content?

Comment: How did you build that array?

Comment: @KimO, Looks like you are using the [wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280303/9209546) from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279973/python-create-structured-numpy-structured-array-from-two-columns-in-a-dataframe) (or didn't read my comment to that answer). Take one step at a time. Understand each step as you go along. This will help you resolve problems more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize the structured array, ensure that you specify the data types.

For example:

```
y = np.array([(True, 144.0), (True, 86.0), (True, 448.0)],
          dtype=[('col_1', 'bool'), ('col_2', 'f4')])
```

This should work and:

```
y.dtype.fields
```

shows as desired:

```
mappingproxy({'col_1': (dtype('bool'), 0), 'col_2': (dtype('float32'), 1)})
```

See the documentation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html

Answer (score 2):

> I have a numpy structured array

No you don't:

> `np.array(..., dtype=object)`

You have a numpy object array, which contains tuples.

You can convert it to a structured array with `y.astype([('b', bool), ('f', float)])`

Answer (score 1):

To create a structured array, *you must specify the dtype beforehand*. If you just use `numpy.array` with a list-literal of pairs then you will get an array with object `dtype`. So, you need to do something like:

```
>>> mytype = np.dtype([('b', bool), ('f',float)])
>>> mytype
dtype([('b', '?'), ('f', '<f8')])
```

Then pass `mytype` to the array constructor:

```
>>> structured = np.array(
...    [(True, 144.0), (True, 86.0),
...     (True, 448.0), (True, 76.0),
...     (True, 511.0), (True, 393.0), 
...     (False, 466.0), (False, 470.0)], dtype=mytype)
>>>
>>> structured
array([( True,  144.), ( True,   86.), ( True,  448.), ( True,   76.),
       ( True,  511.), ( True,  393.), (False,  466.), (False,  470.)],
      dtype=[('b', '?'), ('f', '<f8')])
```