# Pandas - Converting data frame into a specific format

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that has two columns as below:

```
col_a,col_b
10,32
23,43
32,64
```

I am trying to get the Dataframe converted to the below format:

```
[(10,32),(23,43),(32,64)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Create structured numpy structured array from two columns in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279973/python-create-structured-numpy-structured-array-from-two-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension or map with convert lists to tuples:

```
L = [tuple(x) for x in df.values.tolist()]
```

---

```
L = list(map(tuple, df.values.tolist()))
```

Another solution with `zip` and transpose:

```
L = list(zip(*df.T.values.tolist()))

print (L)
[(10, 32), (23, 43), (32, 64)]
```