# how to count the sum satisfying a condition with Numpy not with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 4 columns (Name, Gender, Number of births) and I want to calculate the total number of females and males and I have to make like a groupby gender.
I've already done it with pandas like this :

`names1880.groupby(['Gender']).sum()`

And I had an ouput like this

```
Gender----|----Births
F         |    166868
----------|------------
M         |    120851
```

But now I have to do it by Numpy not with Pandas

Comment: Try this `np.unique(a, return_counts=True)`

Comment: Also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373631/sum-array-by-number-in-numpy

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.bincount` is a good tool for this if you use the birth counts as weights. But `bincount` requires that the categories be integers. So you can do this in numpy if you first create an array with different integers for each gender, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names1880 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Walter', 'Roger', 'Jane', 'Imelda'],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female'],
    'Births': [100, 200, 120, 220]
})

gender_names, gender_codes = np.unique(
    names1880['Gender'], return_inverse=True
)
print(gender_names)
print(np.bincount(gender_codes, weights=names1880['Births']))

# ['Female' 'Male']
# [340. 300.]
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, I had this error : ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'F' .         And I have to make a sum of variables not a count :'(

Comment: @SarahKraiem I added some code to categorize the genders first, so bincount can work with them. Note that bincount will calculate a sum of the birth counts if you use the birth counts as weights.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this SO answer for converting pandas DataFrame to numpy structured array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280608/42346

```
import collections as co, numpy as np, pandas as pd

# my simple test DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(co.OrderedDict([('Name',['test','test2','test3']),
                                  ('Gender',['female','male','female']),
                                  ('Number of births',[2,3,4])])) 

# convert pandas DataFrame to numpy structured array 
# credit to this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280608/42346
sarr = np.array([tuple(x) for x in df.values], 
                dtype=list(zip(df.dtypes.index, df.dtypes)))

# finally get the totals by group
for k in np.unique(sarr['Gender']): 
    print(k, sum(sarr[sarr['Gender'] == k]['Number of births']))
```

Result:

```
female 6
male 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did simply this :
to count all births :

```
All_births = names1880.sum()
```

and to filter I did this :

```
names1880[names1880['Gender'] == "F"].sum()
```

and

```
names1880[names1880['Gender'] == "M"].sum()
```