# How to change the dtype of a numpy recarray when one of the columns is an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, fits

In [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949427/how-to-change-the-dtype-of-a-numpy-recarray) I've seen that changing `dtype` of a `recarray` can be performed using `astype`. However I cannot manage to do it with a `recarray` which has an array in one of its columns.

My `recarray` comes from a FITS file record:

```py
> f = fits.open('myfile.fits')   
> tbdata = f[1].data
> tbdata
# FITS_rec([ (0.27591679999999996, array([570, 576, 566, ..., 571, 571, 569], dtype=int16)),
#   (0.55175680000000005, array([575, 563, 565, ..., 572, 577, 582], dtype=int16)),
#   ...,
#   (2999.2083967999997, array([574, 570, 575, ..., 560, 551, 555], dtype=int16)),
#   (2999.4842367999995, array([575, 583, 578, ..., 559, 565, 568], dtype=int16)], 
#   dtype=[('TIME', '>f8'), ('AC', '>i4', (2,))])
```

I need to convert *AC* column from `int` to `float` so I've tried:

```py
> tbdata = tbdata.astype([('TIME', '>f8'), ('AC', '>f4', (2,))])
```

and, although it seems that `dtype` has indeed changed

```py
> tbdata.dtype
# dtype([('TIME', '>f8'), ('AC', '>f4', (2,))])
```

a look to the data in *AC* shows that they are still integer values. For instance, a `sum` calculation reaches the limits of the `int16` variable (all the *AC* column values are positive):

```py
> tbdata['AC'][0:55].sum()
# _VLF(array([31112, 31128, 31164, ..., 31203, 31232, 31262], dtype=int16), dtype=object)
> tbdata['AC'][0:65].sum()
# _VLF(array([-28766, -28759, -28702, ..., -28659, -28638, -28583], dtype=int16), dtype=object)
```

Is there any way to effectively change the array data type?

Comment: Not an answer, just curious: According to the dtype, the 'AC' field is an array with shape (2,).  Why does the commented output show this field as having many more elements?  E.g. `array([570, 576, 566, ..., 571, 571, 569], dtype=int16)`

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but I'm not using your FITS library.  A self-contained example that we can copy and run would be helpful.  Don't use the FITS data; just create a simple dtype and array "by hand" that can be used to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser : for the first question, I'm not sure, but I guess this is something related to the fact that the 'AC' field is a FITS variable length array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue with a `recarray` from a fits file. 
A workaround is to load the `recarray` as a fits table, and then transform it into a pandas dataframe:

```
from astropy.table import Table
import pandas as pd

t = Table.read('file.fits')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(t, columns=t.columns) 
df.AC = df.AC.astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Warren advice, if I try with a `recarray` created "by hand", things seem to go well:

```
> ra = np.array([ ([30000,10000], 1), ([30000,20000],2),([30000,30000],3) ], dtype=[('x', 'int16',2), ('y', int)])
> ra
# array([([30000, 10000], 1), ([30000, 20000], 2), ([30000, 30000], 3)],
#       dtype=[('x', '<i2', (2,)), ('y', '<i8')])
> ra = ra.astype([('x', '<f4', (2,)), ('y', '<i8')])
> ra
# array([([30000.0, 10000.0], 1), ([30000.0, 20000.0], 2),
#        ([30000.0, 30000.0], 3)], dtype=[('x', '<f4', (2,)), ('y', '<i8')])
```

So, int16 numbers **are** converted to float numbers.

However, after the `astype` call to my *tbdata* `recarray`, numbers do not seem to change at all (nor the internal `dtype`):

```
> tbdata.dtype
# dtype([('TIME', '>f8'), ('AC', '>f4', (2,))])
> tbdata
# FITS_rec([ (0.27591679999999996, array([570, 576, 566, ..., 571, 571, 569], dtype=int16)),
#    (0.55175680000000005, array([575, 563, 565, ..., 572, 577, 582], dtype=int16)),
#   ...,
#   (2999.2083967999997, array([574, 570, 575, ..., 560, 551, 555], dtype=int16)),
#   (2999.4842367999995, array([575, 583, 578, ..., 559, 565, 568], dtype=int16))], 
#    dtype=[('TIME', '>f8'), ('ADC', '<f4', (2,))])
```

My conclusion is that this can be a problem related to the [AstroPy](http://www.astropy.org) interface to FITS files. In addition, the negative numbers that I retrieve after the `sum()` are in fact not related to the datatype, but they are present in the middle of the integer array in *tbdata*, due to the way FITS stores numbers greater than 32768, using the TZERO keyword for the offset of unsigned integers. The problem is that CFITSIO and normal FITS viewers reconvert these numbers in a transparent way for the user, and thus I was not aware of these negative numbers.
Thanks a lot for help and suggestions.